# Correctly configure service fabric ARM for Azure managed identity on VM scale sets

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-managed-identity

Trying to set up Managed Identity for Azure service fabric VM scale set nodes.  If you are not familiar with that concept you can read up on that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/concepts-managed-identity).

Running locally in Visual Studio it runs with DefaultAzureCredential using environment variables but on the server it is supposed to used managed identity.

In my Service fabric ARM template I have this set up:

```
"apiVersion": "[variables('vmssApiVersion')]", "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets", "name": "[variables('vmNodeType0Name')]", "location": "[variables('computeLocation')]", "dependsOn": [ "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]", "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[0])]", "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[1])]", "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[2])]", "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[3])]", "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('uniqueStringArray0')[4])]", "[concat('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/', concat('LB','-', parameters('clusterName'),'-',variables('vmNodeType0Name')))]", "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('supportLogStorageAccountName'))]", "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('applicationDiagnosticsStorageAccountName'))]" ], "identity": { "type": "UserAssigned", "userAssignedIdentities": { "[resourceId(parameters('userAssignedIdentityResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/', parameters('userAssignedIdentityName'))]": {} } },
```

In my code I have it set up like this with `DefaultAzureCredential`:

```
var keyVaultClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(this.keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

When I run the app on the server it throws this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application. EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot] System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage) +68 Azure.Identity.d__12.MoveNext() +1353 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Identity.d__11.MoveNext() +859 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Identity.d__14.MoveNext() +1040

[AggregateException: Multiple exceptions were encountered while attempting to authenticate.]

[CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot

EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.
Visual Studio Token provider can't be accessed at .IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json
Azure CLI not installed
Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed.] Azure.Identity.d__14.MoveNext() +1426 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Identity.d__12.MoveNext() +3077 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage) +68 Azure.Identity.d__12.MoveNext() +3770 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Identity.d__11.MoveNext() +859 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Core.Pipeline.d__9.MoveNext() +919 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Core.Pipeline.d__6.MoveNext() +2057 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Core.Pipeline.d__6.MoveNext() +3171 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Core.Pipeline.d__12.MoveNext() +634 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Security.KeyVault.d__7.MoveNext() +728 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Core.Pipeline.d__11.MoveNext() +601 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Core.Pipeline.d__7.MoveNext() +529 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Core.Pipeline.d__11.MoveNext() +1157 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 Azure.Core.Pipeline.d__11.MoveNext() +3724 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Core.Pipeline.d__18.MoveNext() +548 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Security.KeyVault.d__29.MoveNext() +602 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Security.KeyVault.d__21`1.MoveNext() +411 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.d__8.MoveNext() +989 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60 Microsoft.Support.Community.KeyVault.d__4.MoveNext() +459
[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.] System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) +4761032 Microsoft.Support.Community.Core.Security.AesEncryption..ctor(IAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider, ILogWriter logWriter) in D:\a\_work\1\b\2\_work\1\s\Product\Community.Core\Security\AesEncryption.cs:60 lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +503 Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35 Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +335 Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +389 Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +130 lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +8828 Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35 Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +335 Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +389 Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable1 resolverOverrides) +451

[ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Support.Community.Portal.Controllers.SiteController", name = "(none)". Exception occurred while: Calling constructor Microsoft.Support.Community.Core.Security.AesEncryption(Microsoft.Support.Community.Core.Security.IAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider, Microsoft.Support.Community.Logging.ILogWriter logWriter). Exception is: AggregateException - One or more errors occurred.
At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving Microsoft.Support.Community.Portal.Controllers.SiteController,(none) Resolving value for property SiteController.AesEncryptionService Resolving Microsoft.Support.Community.Core.Security.AesEncryption,(none) (mapped from Microsoft.Support.Community.Core.Security.IAesEncryptionService, (none)) Calling constructor Microsoft.Support.Community.Core.Security.AesEncryption(Microsoft.Support.Community.Core.Security.IAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider, Microsoft.Support.Community.Logging.ILogWriter logWriter) ] Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +551 Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) +20 Microsoft.Support.Community.Portal.Classes.UnityControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in D:\a_work\1\b\2_work\1\s\Product\Community.Portal\Classes\UnityControllerFactory.cs:37 System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +103 Microsoft.CommonSchema.Services.Mvc.Internal.CaptureControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +25 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +263 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +77 Microsoft.CommonSchema.Services.Mvc.Internal.CaptureHandler.BeginProcessRequest(IHttpAsyncHandler handler, HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +256 System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +1122 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +213 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +131

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3690.0
```

Comment: The `DefaultAzureCredential` tries a number of methods to obtain a credential. If one fails it continues with the other methods as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet#definition). In your case it seems none of the available methods where available to create credentials. Given this line: *ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.* I suspect something is not configured correctly when following the steps to enable MI for SF.

Comment: From your code and config you show in the question it is hard to tell whether this is the case or not.

Answer (score 0):

When using a user assigned managed identity, you could in theory provide multiple. Therefore, you need to specify its Client ID, so the code knows which one to use.

```
string userAssignedClientId = "<your managed identity client Id>";
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId });

var keyVaultClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(this.keyVaultUrl), credential);
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet#examples).